# moment.startOf month goes to 31st of previous month

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

In order to aggregate some things I need to set the month in a data Object. I'm trying to get the start of each month by using this code

```
moment("2018-09-04T13:06:07.397Z").startOf('month').toDate()
```

This however returns Date 2018-08-31T22:00:00.000Z.

How can I return the start of this actual month?

Comment: Your input string ends with `Z`, so represent time in UTC, you have to parse it using [`moment.utc(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) instead of [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Comment: Thanks! works fine now

Comment: @VincenzoC make your comment into an answer. Then it should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: @ChrisCousins I was looking for a dupe target, but I didn't find one, so I've added my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input string ends with `Z`, so represent time in UTC, you have to parse it using [`moment.utc(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) instead of [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

```js
console.log(moment.utc("2018-09-04T13:06:07.397Z").startOf('month').toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```